# Python File read write operations

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, exception

How to handle FileNotFoundError when opening a file which is not present using with open("testfile",'r') as F1:

I am able to handle it using traditional try,except,else,finally block

Comment: If you're able to handle it then what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try and except block to catch the error , and use `with open` instead of only `open` , so you don't need to worry about closing the file.

```
try:
    with open("testfile",'r') as F1:
        #Do you stuff
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```